# Obscure gnu_stl crash

Tags: android, c++, gcc, stl, android-ndk

I'm getting a rather obscure crash from the my application, using the Android NDK.

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/jfltexx/jflte:4.4.2/KOT49H/I9505XXUGNE5:user/release-keys'
pid: 4447, tid: 4447, name: com.redacted  >>> com.redacted <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000004
Stack frame #00  pc 0111086e  /data/app-lib/com.redacted-1/libcocos2dcpp.so: Routine local_Rb_tree_decrement at /s/ndk-toolchain/src/gcc/gcc-4.9/libstdc++-v3/src/c++98/tree.cc:98
Stack frame #01  pc 006329f0  /data/app-lib/com.redacted-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> >::operator--()+28): Routine std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> >::operator--() at /Users/arvidgerstmann/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/stl_tree.h:218
Stack frame #02  pc 00632934  /data/app-lib/com.redacted-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, std::string>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > >::_M_get_insert_unique_pos(std::string const&)+324): Routine std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, std::string>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > >::_M_get_insert_unique_pos(std::string const&) at /Users/arvidgerstmann/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/stl_tree.h:1494
Stack frame #03  pc 006320f8  /data/app-lib/com.redacted-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, std::string>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > >::_M_get_insert_hint_unique_pos(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> >, std::string const&)+268): Routine std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, std::string>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > >::_M_get_insert_hint_unique_pos(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> >, std::string const&) at /Users/arvidgerstmann/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/stl_tree.h:1586
Stack frame #04  pc 007017fc  /data/app-lib/com.redacted-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZNSt8_Rb_treeISsSt4pairIKSsSsESt10_Select1stIS2_ESt4lessISsESaIS2_EE22_M_emplace_hint_uniqueIJRKSt21piecewise_construct_tSt5tupleIJRS1_EESD_IJEEEEESt17_Rb_tree_iteratorIS2_ESt23_Rb_tree_const_iteratorIS2_EDpOT_+152): Routine std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, std::string>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > >::_M_emplace_hint_unique<std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<std::string const&>, std::tuple<> >(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> >, std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<std::string const&>&&, std::tuple<>&&) at /Users/arvidgerstmann/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/stl_tree.h:1834 (discriminator 2)
```

I am using `GCC 4.9` with the corresponding `GNU_STL`, to build the project on Android. It works fine with `clang` and there standard c++ library.
The crash occurs directly after starting, it's not even entering my `main()` function.

Comment: Start by building with more warnings enabled, warnings can indicate you doing something you should not do and that may lead to undefined behavior. Then take a look at all your global and static variables, any of them initialized in a way they shouldn't, like dereferencing uninitialized variables or constructing objects which expects other things to be initialized, or depend on initialization order which  might be what you expect?

Comment: Oh, and if it crashes in the emulator, then you can run in a debugger to find the source.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have tons of warnings enabled, and the code is regularly checked by a static analyzer. Everything works perfectly and as expected with clang, but not with gcc. It's not particularly an issue with my code (it could be, though).

Comment: It's failing in some tree traversal code, while emplacing something into a `map<string,string>`. Most likely either the map's internal rbtree is damaged, or you have a synchronization problem. If `main` hasn't started yet, that just means your static initialization includes `std::map` operations.

Comment: I don't have any static `std::map`s, I have also checked anything related to maps, but I recently added a few const `std::array`s. Let me take a look.

Comment: Ok, that was the culprit. But why is an `std::array` referring to code  in `std::map`? Isn't it basically an STL wrapper around a default C++ array?

Comment: Do the contained class have a `std::tree` in it? Because just line a normal array `std::array` constructs all its elements when the array itself is constructed.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No, it consists of `std::string`s.